# Is there a Typescript equivalent of ESLint's no-implicit-coercion?

Tags: typescript

Is there a Typescript equivalent of ESLint's no-implicit-coercion?

I want to protect against the scenario where someone is doing interpolation and ends up with an object.

```
const user = { name: 'John', lastname: 'Doe' }
console.log(`Hello ${user}`)
// Hello [object Object]
```

Maybe there's other ways to this than preventing implicit coercion too?

Comment: The TypeScript equivalent oif ESList **is** ESLint... well, a modded ESLint: https://typescript-eslint.io/ - so just use that instead of ESLint, but otherwise use it as normal.

Answer (score 0):

You could always have a type check before interpolating - for example in form of a function, that only takes strings and returns the string - this way you'll get a compiler error if you try to interpolate sth. that's not a string. See example below:

```
function interpol(str: string): string {
    return str
}

const user = { name: 'John', lastname: 'Doe' }
console.log(`Hello ${interpol(user)}`)
```